Как убрать ограничение оперативной памяти в приложениях
Решил проверить сколько используется оперативной памяти во время игры а то уж тяжело играть с провисаниями, и заметил то что приложение максимально использует 1.6гб оперативной, имеется 8гб и 8гб расшириной, решил полазить по настройкам что бы увеличить ограничение, но не нашёл как , в интернете способов так же не нашёл

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
